# How do i rerender my screen after deletion from list?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, react-native

Hello I've been looking through several threads on stackoverflow but I haven't been able to solve my problem. I have an app where you can save movies to a watchlist. On this specific screen I want to display a users watchlist and give them the ability to delete it from the list. Currently the function is indeed deleting the movie from the list and removing it from firebase but i can't get my screen to rerender to visually represent the deletion.

This is the code right now:

```
export default function MovieWatchlistTab(props: any) {
  let { movies } = props;
  let movieWatchlist: any[] = [];
  const [watchlistSnapshot, setWatchlistSnapshot] = useState();
  const user: firebase.User = auth().currentUser;
  const { email } = user;
  const watchlistRef = firestore().collection("Watchlist");

  useEffect(() => {
    getWatchlistSnapshot();
  }, []);

  const getWatchlistSnapshot = async () => {
    setWatchlistSnapshot(await watchlistRef.where("userId", "==", email).get());
  };

  const convertDataToArray = () => {
    const convertedMovieList = [];
    for (let movie in movies) {
      let newMovie = {
        backdrop: movies[movie].backdrop,
        overview: movies[movie].overview,
        release: movies[movie].release,
        title: movies[movie].title,
      };
      convertedMovieList.push(newMovie);
    }
    movieWatchlist = convertedMovieList;
  };

  const renderMovieList = () => {
    convertDataToArray();
    return movieWatchlist.map((m) => {
      const handleOnPressDelete = () => {
        const documentRef = watchlistRef.doc(watchlistSnapshot.docs[0].id);
        const FieldValue = firestore.FieldValue;
        documentRef.set(
          {
            movies: {
              [m.title]: FieldValue.delete(),
            },
          },
          { merge: true }
        );
        movieWatchlist.splice(
          movieWatchlist.indexOf(m),
          movieWatchlist.indexOf(m) + 1
        );
        console.log("movieWatchlist", movieWatchlist);
      };

      const swipeButtons = [
        {
          text: "Delete",
          color: "white",
          backgroundColor: "#b9042c",
          onPress: handleOnPressDelete,
        },
      ];
      return (
        <Swipeout right={swipeButtons} backgroundColor={"#18181b"}>
          <View key={m.title} style={{ marginTop: 10, flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Image
              style={{ height: 113, width: 150 }}
              source={{
                uri: m.backdrop,
              }}
            />
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  color: "white",
                  marginLeft: 10,
                  fontSize: 17,
                }}
              >
                {m.title}
              </Text>
              <Text style={{ flex: 1, color: "white", marginLeft: 10 }}>
                Release: {m.release}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Swipeout>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#18181b",
      }}
    >
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        }}
      >
        {renderMovieList()}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I've been trying to play around with useStates and I think the answer is in that direction but I just can't seem to get it to work anyway. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: before removing from firebase, filter the item from the array and show the filtered array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few lines in your code that show a misunderstand of React state.  You have a value `let movieWatchlist: any[] = [];` that you reassign in `convertDataToArray()` and mutate in `handleOnPressDelete`.  That's just not how we do things in React and it's not going to trigger updates properly.  `movieWatchlist` either needs to be a stateful variable created with `useState`.

Do the `movies` passed in through `props` change?  If they do, then you don't need to store them in `state` here.  You could just `return` an `array` from `convertDataToArray()` rather than setting a variable and returning `void`.

To be honest it's really not clear what `convertDataToArray` is even doing as it seems like `newMovie` is either the same or a subset of the original movie object.  If the point is to remove the other properties aside from these four, that's not actually needed.  If the prop `movies` is already an array, just delete this whole function and use `movies` directly.  If it's a keyed object, use `Object.values(movies)` to get it as an array.

I'm thoroughly confused as to what we are getting from `props` and what we are getting from firebase.  It seems like we would want to update the snapshot state after deletion, but you only run your `useEffect` once on mount.

You may still have errors, but this code should be an improvement:

```
interface Movie {
  backdrop: string;
  overview: string;
  release: string;
  title: string;
}

const MovieThumbnail = (props: Movie) => (
  <View key={props.title} style={{ marginTop: 10, flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <Image
      style={{ height: 113, width: 150 }}
      source={{
        uri: props.backdrop
      }}
    />
    <View>
      <Text
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          color: "white",
          marginLeft: 10,
          fontSize: 17
        }}
      >
        {props.title}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ flex: 1, color: "white", marginLeft: 10 }}>
        Release: {props.release}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);

export default function MovieWatchlistTab() {
  const [watchlistSnapshot, setWatchlistSnapshot] = useState<DocumentSnapshot>();
  const user: firebase.User = auth().currentUser;
  const { email } = user;
  const watchlistRef = firestore().collection("Watchlist");

  const getWatchlistSnapshot = async () => {
    const results = await watchlistRef.where("userId", "==", email).get();
    setWatchlistSnapshot(results.docs[0]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getWatchlistSnapshot();
  }, []);

  const deleteMovie = async (title: string) => {
    if ( ! watchlistSnapshot ) return;
    const documentRef = watchlistRef.doc(watchlistSnapshot.id);
    const FieldValue = firestore.FieldValue;
    await documentRef.set(
      {
        movies: {
          [title]: FieldValue.delete()
        }
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
    // reload watch list
    getWatchlistSnapshot();
  };

  // is this right?  I'm just guessing
  const movies = ( watchlistSnapshot ? watchlistSnapshot.data().movies : []) as Movie[];

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#18181b"
      }}
    >
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          width: Dimensions.get("window").width
        }}
      >
        {movies.map((m) => (
          <Swipeout
            right={[
              {
                text: "Delete",
                color: "white",
                backgroundColor: "#b9042c",
                // need to pass the title to the delete handler
                onPress: () => deleteMovie(m.title)
              }
            ]}
            backgroundColor={"#18181b"}
          >
            <MovieThumbnail {...m} />
          </Swipeout>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```